# How to combine same value for Google sheet query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to create a separate tab in my Google sheet where I can filter the Trainer to see which days they will be conducting a Day 1 and Day 2 Training.

**Day 1 Training:**

```
=iferror(
     query('Hiring Tracker'!N:Q,
     "Select N Where O = '"&A2&"' and N >= date '"&G2&"' order by N asc"
     ,0
     )
)
```

**Day 2 Training:**

```
=iferror(
    query('Hiring Tracker'!N:Q,
    "Select P Where Q = '"&A2&"' and P >= date '"&G2&"' order by P asc"
    ,0
    )
)
```

But instead of showing multiple same dates, is there a way I can combine the same values to show which days the Trainer will be training. The chart on the right is what I want to have and the chart on the left is what I have right now.

[image]

[Training Doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hd9S1w1XO2MlnW_NXOmxFaqieKNyX-CWBapeyGdu1p0/edit#gid=1629646265)

Comment: You're leaking a thousand emails together with first/last names and location on your shared Google doc - this is not good practice. You're lucky these are not EU residents - otherwise you'd get into trouble. Even worse, through the "Importrange" sheet ID, I could view the actual worksheet you're working on - seeing everything. Not great.

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula `=unique`

**Day 1 Training:**

```
=UNIQUE(iferror(
             query('Hiring Tracker'!N:Q,
             "Select N Where O = '"&A2&"' and N >= date '"&G2&"' order by N asc"
             ,0
             )
))
```

**Day 2 Training:**

```
=UNIQUE(iferror(
            query('Hiring Tracker'!N:Q,
            "Select P Where Q = '"&A2&"' and P >= date '"&G2&"' order by P asc"
            ,0
            )
))
```